# where to get ubuntu phone/touch daily updates for the nexus 4?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I'm currently using ubuntu touch (mako #17) on my new nexus 4 (my only phone) and I'm having difficulties finding where ? to get the daily builds or latest releases for the phablet-flash.

I have followed the touch wiki, added the PPA, and i do daily phablet-flash updates, but still after a week I keep getting the same "old"? #17 version, what, if anything, am I doing wrong?

best regards from sweden

Comment: You should be using the builds from: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/ *Which Wiki / install instructions did you follow?*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering

I used the method described in this (official?) one : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

So how do i go about flashing these daily builds to my phone, is there a PPA and howto guide similar to the one described in the wiki (above) ?

If not a terminal command instruction would be very much appreciated, if you or anybody has the possibility and time to help me out with this.

The reson is that I keep seeing these much more developed versions popping up on youtube and other places and it seems I running a dated version, I am aware of the risks involved.

Comment: The same build (as I noted) are used by the Wiki page you found.